# simple shell script syntax error : [ : missing ']'

Tags: c++, shell, debugging, ubuntu, command

I am trying to do following shell equivalent of the following c++ script

```
int x=1;
int y=2;
int k=0;

for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
   {

       if ( (x==1) && (y==2) )
       {
           k=1;
       }

   }
 }
```

I am always getting weird synatax error like there must be spaces between `[`  or something else , i am confident its one of these reason

This is what my sample code looks like

```
    for x in ${title[@]} 
    do

    for y in ${author[@]} 
    do
        if [ [ $x == $1] && [ $y == $2] ]; # error : [: missing ']'
        then
            error=1
            return "$error"
        fi
    done
   done
```

**How do i resolve it**

Comment: The `]` must be a separate argument; it is not a keyword.  So, at minimum you need a space between the 2 and the `]`.  That then leaves you with an invalid outer `[` command; you need to use either the `[[` and `]]` test, or you need to rewrite the `[` ... `]` command more carefully (arguably, as two invocations of the `[` command).

Comment: It would help if you specified *which* shell you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `if [ [ $x == $1] && [ $y == $2] ];` by `if [[ $x == $1 && $y == $2 ]];`

Comment: I think you have to use either `[ "$x" = "$1" ] && [ "$y" = "$2" ]` or `[[ "$x" == "$1" && "$y" == "$2" ]]` where the quotes might not be necessary in the second (thanks to some special-casing rules, which just make life more complicated) but are definitely strongly recommended in the first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe your 2 solutions are logically equivalent to my solution :) Yours being safer by using the quotes.

Comment: The `&&` is not a valid operator to the classic `[` command (you used `-a` for _and_ and `-o` for _or_); it might be OK in `bash`, but the documentation doesn't say so.  See [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) and [Bourne shell builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) in the Bash manual.

Comment: @ Lefebvre Your solution doesn work :( , John solutions works :)

Comment: @Computernerd Yes I realized that :/ I edited my answer with the correct way